# Parsing date in pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am trying to read a CSV file which has in its first column date values specified in this format:

```
"Dec 30, 2021","1.1","1.2","1.3","1"
```

While I can define the types for the remaining columns using `dtype=` clause, I do not know how to handle the Date.

I have tried the obvious `np.datetime64` without success.

Is there any way to specify a format to parse this date directly using `read_csv` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify a list of columns that should be convert to dates in the `parse_dates=` of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
>>> df
        date    a    b    c  d
0 2021-12-30  1.1  1.2  1.3  1

>>> df.dtypes
date    datetime64[ns]
a              float64
b              float64
c              float64
d                int64
```

Comment: thanks. What if I want to further specify the format for a,b,c and d? I used a simplified example, in my file numbers are formated like this `"2,345.55"` and those are read as `object` by read_csv, not as float64 or int64 as in your example.

Comment: pandas seems to be able to figure out format, so richardec answer works. Unfortunatelly my particular example includes the rest of columns with a different format, maybe I shall open another question.

Answer (score 4):

You may use parse_dates :

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
```

But in my experience it is a frequent source of errors, I think it is better to specify the date format and convert manually the date column. For example, in your case :

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%b %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

> What if I want to further specify the format for a,b,c and d? I used a simplified example, in my file numbers are formated like this "2,345.55" and those are read as object by read_csv, not as float64 or int64 as in your example

```
converters = {
    'Date': lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%b %d, %Y"),
    'Number': lambda x: float(x.replace(',', ''))
}
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters=converters)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Date   Number
0 2021-12-30  2345.55

>>> df.dtypes
Date      datetime64[ns]
Number           float64
dtype: object

# data.csv
Date,Number
"Dec 30, 2021","2,345.55"
```

---

**Old answer**

If you have a particular format, you can pass a custom function to `date_parser` parameter:

```
from datetime import datetime

custom_date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%b %d, %Y")
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser=custom_date_parser)
print(df)

# Output
        Date    A    B    C  D
0 2021-12-30  1.1  1.2  1.3  1
```

Or let Pandas try to determine the format as suggested by @richardec.

Comment: @M.E. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?