# How do I parse numbers with thousands separator in pandas read_csv?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a CSV file with lines as follows:

"Dec 30, 2021","1,234.11","1,654.22","11,876.23","1,676,234"

I have learn from a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568436/parsing-date-in-pandas-read-csv/) that I can use:

```
parse_dates=['Date']
```

To get the date parsed (that works).
However I would like columns 2-4 as np.float64 and column 5 as int64. How can I achieve that?

I have tried this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv",  parse_dates=['Date'], dtype=[np.datetime64, np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, np.int64])
```

but I get

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: Your columns have name or not?

Comment: Yes they do have names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas reading CSV data formatted with comma for thousands separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439933/pandas-reading-csv-data-formatted-with-comma-for-thousands-separator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `thousands` parameter.

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",  parse_dates=['Date'], thousands=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `converters` parameter if you have special format.

```
converters = {
    'Date': lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%b %d, %Y"),
    'Number': lambda x: float(x.replace(',', ''))
}
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters=converters)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Date   Number
0 2021-12-30  2345.55

>>> df.dtypes
Date      datetime64[ns]
Number           float64
dtype: object

# data.csv
Date,Number
"Dec 30, 2021","2,345.55"
```

Else use standard parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",  header=None, parse_dates=[0], thousands=',', quoting=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           0        1        2         3        4
0 2021-12-30  1234.11  1654.22  11876.23  1676234

>>> df.dtypes
0    datetime64[ns]
1           float64
2           float64
3           float64
4             int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, this is very comprehensive. I chosed `thousands=` answer as it seems more idiomatic/simple in pandas.